# OSX X11 Error cannot open display

Tags: macos, docker, x11

I am trying to run any GUI container I can on MacOS. With every container I try (firefox, chrome, tor, spotify, etc) I always get the error `Error: cannot open display`. And it's not specific to the `docker run` command where I pass the environment flag with my `$DISPLAY`. When I try to run `xhost +` I get the same error.

I have a fresh XQuartz installation. It is up and running. I have turned on "allow connections from network" under security. I've tried building my own images and pulling jessie frazelle's images. I do not suspect it is a docker issue or the Dockerfiles. It is something on the host, my laptop. I can't seem to figure out what it is.

MacOS Sierra 10.12.5
Docker 17.12.0 Stable
XQuartz 2.7.11 (xorg-server 1.18.4)
My local's `$DISPLAY` is set to `:0.0`

Comment: Try setting `DISPLAY` to your Mac's IP address, e.g. `$(ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet /{print $2 ":0"}')`

Comment: This seems to sort of helped. I get mixed results. Examples;  

    $ echo $DISPLAY
    192.169.1.11:0
    $ xhost +
    xhost:  unable to open display "192.169.1.11:0"  

I only did the above as a test after trying the containers again, just to see. This is the same results as before, however it takes WAAAYYYY longer now. Including the containers that give me this error.  

The 3 containers (tor, chrome, ff) I tried which all gave me the original error "unable to open display". Only tor and ff gave me this error this time. All still don't work, but they are all permissions issues

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So I finally got this to work. And it seems it was pretty simple. I am not certain how this actually fixes the issue, but now the containers work.

How I fixed it was opening up XQuartz and then opening up the "Terminal" app from the "Applications" menu. Then running the command `export DISPLAY=192.168.1.X:0`, then `xhost +`. It outputted something like this "access control disabled, clients can connect from any host". After that I was able to run my `docker run` commands to launch the desired GUI containers.

I am still uncertain how this works and not running them from my laptops Terminal app, but it worked. It must be something I have set in my local env. Hopefully this helps someone else out who may be running into the same issues.

Comment: ... good that you got it worked out but even so `xhost +` is insecure and that should be pointed out ... still good that you got it sorted for yourself.

Answer (score 15):

Based on @Byron's answer, I've found out that I could get it to work by running these 2 commands in the normal terminal:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
/opt/X11/bin/xhost +
```

Comment: Sorry, none of them did work on my Mac OS: 10.14.6. Could you let me know what could be right steps for Mac OS. I'm actually trying to launch Oracle's runInstaller instead of docker run

Comment: Thanks @lucas-pottersky. It worked for me

MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
Docker 20.10.14
XQuartz 2.8.1 (xorg-server 1.20.11)

Comment: It should be noted that this is insecure, using `xhost +`. I'm not sure if there's always a better solution but if there is it should definitely be used.